# IE Font Expanding Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have asked this question before, however I was too vague (just getting used to the Stack Overflow etiquette).

I have taken over the webmaster duties of a site that someone else created, and have run into a browser specific issue with fonts and Internet Explorer. It seems that the menu is fine in every browser but IE.

Below is an imgur album featuring 2 images (sorry for the blue paint, there for confidentiality I suppose). In the Firefox snapshot, the bottom navigation menu is all on the same line, however in the IE snapshot some of the text is being pushed to the second line. I am assuming this is a CSS issue, but I need to be sure.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjUas.png

The code - the footer is a PHP include with the following code:

```
<link href="css/newFooter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="footer_nav">

    <ul class="footer_nav_list">
        <li class="rightindent">&copy;2014 My Company, LLC&nbsp; &nbsp; All Rights Reserved.</li>           
        <li><a href="index.php">HOME&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="new-solutions.php">NEW SOLUTIONS&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="other-solutions.php">OTHER SOLUTIONS&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="support.php">SUPPORT&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="careers.php">CAREERS&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT US&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li>            
        <li><a href="sitemap.php">SITEMAP&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is linking to a CSS style-sheet with the following information:

```
/* STRUCTURE BEGINS */
#footer_nav {
background-color: #2f2f2f;
background-image: url(../images/productsMain/footerBg.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
width: 940px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-left: 30px;
float: left;
}
#footer_nav .footer_nav_list {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: #999;
list-style-type: none;
padding-top: 35px;
}
#footer_nav .footer_nav_list ul {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: 15px;
}
#footer_nav .footer_nav_list li  {
display: inline;
}
#footer_nav .footer_nav_list li a {
color: #999;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-left: 2px;
}
#footer_nav .footer_nav_list li a:hover {
color: #FFF;
}
#footer_nav .footer_nav_list .rightindent {
padding-right: 25px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is simply caused by font rendering not being a strictly defined standard. It seems that in IE it takes a little more width to render the text, and that's pushing the last items on the new line. Best solution would be defining an explicit width on the items - worst case, IE overlaps the text of the items just a little, so you may wish to try a slightly smaller font size.

Answer (score 0):

every browser render fonts in a slight different way, there's not much you can about it.
try adding this in `head`

```
<!-- Windows/IE font smoothing -->
<meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
```

Comment: The culprit happens to be located in a PHP include (my footer). Would I have to add this to the <head> section of every page or?

Comment: yes but it's not a guarantee it's gonna do something good for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just change to this for IE (`padding-left:1px`). Yeah, it would be a conditional style "hack" but should work:

```
#footer_nav .footer_nav_list li a {
color: #999;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-left: 1px;
}
```